# How to run the subquery with the non equality clause on Spark?

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I have this query and I want to execute it on spark

```
SELECT A.PFR,
       A.MFR,
       A.MST,

  (SELECT COUNT(*)
   FROM Table1 T2
   WHERE T1.PFR = T2.PFR
     AND T1.MFR = T2.MFR
     AND T1.MST >= T2.MST) AS RANK
FROM Table1 A
```

But spark didn't support subquery with non equality clause

I get this error

> The correlated scalar subquery can only contain equality predicates

So I tried to use `group by` but I didn't get the correct results (I have the input and the out result)

```
SELECT A.PFR,
       A.MFR,
       A.MST,
       B.countRank
FROM Table1 A
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT PFR,
          MFR,
          MST,
          COUNT(MFR) countRank
   FROM Table1 B
   GROUP BY PFR,
            MFR,
            MST) B ON B.PFR = A.PFR
```

There are a method to convert this query to a join query.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: . . You should provide sample data and desired results so it is clear what you want.  Your code does not produce an actual ranking (as usually defined).  If there are 3 ties for the top value, the lowest rank is `3` rather than `1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `rank()`:

```
SELECT A.PFR, A.MFR, A.MST,
       RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY PFR, MFR
                    ORDER BY MST DESC
                   ) as rank
FROM Table1 A;
```

If `rank()` doesn't do exactly what you want, then perhaps `row_number()` or `dense_rank()` work.

Comment: Work great, i forgot the rank function !! thank you